# GXT Borderlayout - West region to stretch to cover both center and south regions

Tags: layout, extjs, border, gxt

Is it possible to configure the west region to stretch till the end of the layout, allowing it to be on the left on both the center and south regions? Meaning, height of west is equal to height of center and south. Instead of having the south region below both west and center regions.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the order of your add-statements?

Instead

add(South), add(West), add(Center)

use

add(West), add(South), add(center).

Comment: Nope, that does not help

Comment: You are right, I thought, it works like a GWT's DockPanel. I think, you need  two BorderLayoutContainer to solve your problem. The first one contains your north widget and your west widget. The center widget of the first BorderLayoutContainer contains a second BorderLayoutContainer and this one contains your south and center widget. This should work.

Comment: But that would also means I can't drag and drop my items? As I am currently dragging from centre to west. Shall give it a try